# If Else on variables and Merge in R

Tags: r

I am facing an issue while merging two data sets.
Suppose there are 2 datasets A and B. And A has been formed by merging X and Y with target variable as abc.

So when I merge A and B, the result of A already formed doesn't reflect on the final dataset of A and B.
Along with this when I merge A and B , my data records count increases in the final dataset . I tried unique() and distinct() functions but not able to apply them on a particular key variable like AgreementID.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Can you try to provide a very small example of your problem/data? (e.g. maybe you are able to recreate the problem by merging to very small datasets). This issue might happen when the elements you are merging on (the "key variable") are not unique in either one of your dataset; other reasons are possible, but without further details it is hard to know.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow!

It's hard to know exactly how to solve your problem given the lack of detail. In future please try to be more precise and give an example of what your data looks like.

I imagine your two datasets A and B are dataframes. Instead of using merge try cbind. Of course cbind will not work if your datasets have different number of rows. The code below adds NAs to the dataframe with the least amount of rows. This will make both data frames have the same number of rows so cbind will work. This is not the most elegant solution but it might work.

```
if(nrow(A) > nrow(B)){
  num.rows <- nrow(A)
}else{
  num.rows <- nrow(B)
}

if (nrow(A) == num.rows){
  n = nrow(A) - nrow(B)
  new.rows <- data.frame(1:n)
  for(i in 1:nrow(new.rows)){
    new.rows[i,,] <- NA
}
B <- rbind(new.rows, B)

}else{
  n = nrow(B) - nrow(A)
  new.rows <- data.frame(1:n)
  for(i in 1:nrow(new.rows)){
  new.rows[i,,] <- NA
}
B <- rbind(new.rows, B)
}
```